# Changing the style of an linked element after the element was clicked and page has reloaded?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to come up with a way to change the styling of an element once it was clicked. In my scenario, once an linked element is clicked, the page is going to reload and I would like to change the style of the element that was clicked after the page has reloaded.

I was able to do this with a bunch of php conditional statements but it seems like its an overkill and I was wondering if someone could help me accomplish this using JQuery?

```
<div>               
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?searchword=toys&resultsperpage=6"><div>6</div></a>
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?searchword=toys&resultsperpage=12"><div>12</div></a>
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?searchword=toys&resultsperpage=24"><div>24</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should say us more about the change you need to happen. What element? What style? What are the matching conditions? etc...

Comment: sounds like you want an "active" style. you can do it with javascript, just pass a class of active to the link that was clicked.

Comment: what do you mean? the elements are posted above. One one of the linked elements above are clicked, the page reloads. I would like to change the background color based on the element that was clicked before the page reloaded.

Comment: @albert how you suggest **at page reload** to pass some states?

Comment: @MHZ it's still not clear: what colors... when... why... Does the color depends on the number inside the link... Tell us more.

Comment: so you want a :visited style? on the link you clicked...then on reload you want that style to be applied....why not just use :visited pseudo class.

Comment: no... as stated in my original post and comment above, the color depends only on the linked element that was clicked before the page reloaded.

Comment: albet I like your suggestion! I'm going to try it.

Comment: MHZ than read the @albert's comment.

Comment: @roko teamwork! also boo to the guy who deleted his answer to not take a points hit. not cool man, not cool

Comment: :visited isn't working w jquery from some reason:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use location.search to get this part of the URL - "?searchword=toys&resultsperpage=6" - and then you can get the right A tag to highlight.

jsFiddle doesn't play nice with query strings but I've managed to create a simple example for you that uses similar approach with location.pathname instead of location.search, please check it here - http://jsfiddle.net/q5y7Z/7/